# Printing a two digit number as character

Tags: c, printf, character, ascii

I have this line of code:

```
printf("%c\n", '65');
```

This code prints `5` to the console.

I know that `65` is not a valid character and is not assigned to any ASCII value, so what is the reason behind this output?

Comment: @Gopi oh! which one?

Comment: But `65` *is* assigned to a valid ASCII character! I don't even have to look it up; it's `A`.

Comment: It turns out it does compile, but it's so wrong I am pissed off. Why does this generate a warning instead of an error? @Jongware it's `65` not `'65'`, see my answer.

Comment: @iharob: no, the OP is right in that this is still valid syntax. It's implementation specific, though, so the reported output may differ per compiler.

Comment: @Jongware i just found out that, updated my answer.

Comment: C allows it as implementation-defined behavior, but that doesn't mean that the code makes any sense on any compiler ever made. GCC seems to print the right-most character in the literal, something that depends on the GCC implementation. It has nothing to do with endianess.

Comment: @Lundin Yes you are right it has nothing to do with endianess and it prints out the right most char and ignores the rest ?

Comment: @Gopi Since it is implementation-defined behavior, it prints whatever the particular compiler for the given system has decided to do when presented with '65'. You'd have to check the specific compiler documentation to know. As we can see from the manual of GCC in one answer below, GCC apparently prints the right-most character.

Comment: @Gopi it does not print out the right most character, it shifts the  leftmost characters by ... read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27982264/1983495).

Comment: @user12345 as this is your first question here, please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 5):

Single quotes give the ascii value of a character and is called a character constant

```
printf("%c\n", '65');
```

is a `multicharacter constant` and this is implementation defined

`65` is the ascii value for the `'A'` character so I suppose you meant

```
printf("%c\n", 'A');
```

which is equivalent to

```
printf("%c\n", 65);
```

Using a multicharacter character constant, is implementation defined. For example `gcc` says

> The compiler evaluates a multi-character character constant a character at a time, shifting the previous value left by the number of bits per target character, and then or-ing in the bit-pattern of the new character truncated to the width of a target character. The final bit-pattern is given type int, and is therefore signed, regardless of whether single characters are signed or not (a slight change from versions 3.1 and earlier of GCC). If there are more characters in the constant than would fit in the target int the compiler issues a warning, and the excess leading characters are ignored.
>
> For example, `'ab'` for a target with an 8-bit char would be interpreted as ‘`(int) ((unsigned char) 'a' * 256 + (unsigned char) 'b')`’, and '`\234a`' as ‘`(int) ((unsigned char) '\234' * 256 + (unsigned char) 'a')`’.
>
> [Reference](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Implementation-defined-behavior.html)

So in `gcc` you would get `5` since

```
printf("%c\n", '65');
```

is equivalent

```
printf("%c\n", (int)(((unsigned char)'6' * 256) | (unsigned char)'5'));
```

Finally from the title of your question, it would seem that you wanted

```
printf("%d\n", 65);
```

i.e. print the decimal value `65`.

Comment: The first sentence says "there are no multicharacter character constants", then you on and quote how e.g. GCC implements them? Multicharacter character constants *are* in the language, with implementation-defined actual values.

Comment: In the last printf the values should be characters and not integers right? Like `printf("%c\n", (int)(((unsigned char)'6' * 256) | (unsigned char)'5'));`

Comment: But your previous printf would have not given the result expected which is `5` now this looks good (+1)

Answer (score 0):

%c prints only a character. %s prints a string.

So try this:

```
printf("%s\n", "65");
```

Source: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

EDIT: If 65 is the decimal number of a character, then write this:

```
printf("%c\n", 65);
```

Comment: And why does OP get the *reported* output? (Well of course I know -- but it would improve your answer.)

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

As we know that a char is 8 bit in size. Here you are trying to print '65' using %c. %c would look for printing 8 bits. '65' is 16 bits : 
Ascii value of 6 is 54, which in binary is 00110110 and that of 5 is 00110101 
So the question is "is %c going to print former 8-bits or latter 8-bits".
Well, that depends on whether your system uses Little Endian or Big Endian.
Big Endian is straight forward and store '54' as 00110110 00110101. But Little Endian stores LSB first and then MSB i.e. 00110101 00110110. It seems that your system supports Little endian and thus %c takes first 8-bits i.e. 00110101, which is 5.

Answer (score 0):

As the character occupies only 1 byte of memory, so whenever you print anything which is more than of 1 byte in the format of a character (i.e. %c), the compiler prints its lower 8 bits (i.e 1 byte) & discarded its all other bits.